# JavaFX - TabPane does not resize when its content height increase after first layout

Tags: java, javafx

I have a javafx application that displays content inside a scrollpane. This content includes a TabPane. Inside the tabpane, there is a VBox containing widgets that can change height based on user interaction, especially:

- table view where more rows are shown
- TitledPane that are expanded.

When this happens, the application does not resize as expected. I understand the problem is that the tabpane does not expand to match its expanded content.

However, the layout would correctly update if I resized the application window, or just selected another tab and then come back in the original tab.

So I believe what is missing is just "triggering" some re-layout. However, I could not manage it by triggering a requestLayout when the tab content is resized. I tried forcing the tabpane minHeight and maxHeight then the tab content is resized also, but it does not work.

See below a sample program that shows the problem (this is javafx 8, but I believe the issue has not been fixed since then)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;

public class TitledPaneBench extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        ScrollPane pane = new ScrollPane();

        VBox box = new VBox();
        box.getChildren().add(new Label("Test"));
        box.getChildren().add(new Label("Test2"));
        box.getChildren().add(new Label("Test3"));


        VBox cbox = new VBox();

        cbox.getChildren().add(new Label("Test ABC"));
        cbox.getChildren().add(new Label("Test CDE"));
        cbox.getChildren().add(new Label("Test DEF"));
        cbox.getChildren().add(new Label("Test EFG"));



        TitledPane titledpane = new TitledPane("Test collapsible",cbox);
        titledpane.setExpanded(false);
        box.getChildren().add(titledpane);
        box.getChildren().add(new Label("Test4"));



        TabPane tabpane = new TabPane();
        Tab tab1 = new Tab();
        tab1.setText("First tab");
        tab1.setContent(box);
        Tab tab2 = new Tab();
        tab2.setText("Faire Valoir");
        tab2.setContent(new Label("Choucroute"));
        tabpane.getTabs().add(tab1);
        tabpane.getTabs().add(tab2);
        box.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> arg0, Number arg1, Number arg2) {
                System.err.println("Height changed "+arg1+" <- "+arg2);
                SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selectionmodel = tabpane.getSelectionModel();
                box.requestLayout();
                tabpane.requestLayout();
            }

        });
        pane.setContent(tabpane);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        stage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        TitledPaneBench tb = new TitledPaneBench();
        tb.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: For future reference you dont need any of this 
   public static void main(String args[]) {
        TitledPaneBench tb = new TitledPaneBench();
        tb.launch(args);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this I moved some things around to clean it up and make it easier for myself to read and understand the line you are looking for is `titledpane.setOnMouseClicked(event -> tabpane.requestLayout());`
 let me know if I misunderstood the problem I can update the answer unless someone else beats me to it

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        VBox cbox = new VBox();
        cbox.getChildren().addAll(
                new Label("Test ABC"),
                new Label("Test CDE"),
                new Label("Test DEF"),
                new Label("Test EFG")
        );
        TabPane tabpane = new TabPane();

        TitledPane titledpane = new TitledPane("Test collapsible",cbox);
        titledpane.setExpanded(false);
        //The line below should solve the issue
        titledpane.setOnMouseClicked(event -> tabpane.requestLayout());

        VBox box = new VBox();
        box.getChildren().addAll(
                new Label("Test"),
                new Label("Test2"),
                new Label("Test3"),
                titledpane,
                new Label("Test4")
        );

        tabpane.getTabs().addAll(
                new Tab("First tab",box),
                new Tab("Faire Valoir",new Label("Choucroute"))
        );

        box.heightProperty().addListener((arg0, arg1, arg2) -> {
            System.err.println("Height changed "+arg1+" <- "+arg2);
            SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selectionmodel = tabpane.getSelectionModel();//Unused
        });

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(tabpane);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(scrollPane));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the help. The solution is working partially when the titled plane is animated (because at the time of the new layout, the titled pane is only partially expanded), but works well when the titledpane is not animated. As I do not plan to animate the titled pane, this is perfect for me.

Comment: Sorry, I am a stack overflow newbie. I validated the answer. Cannot update it yet as I do not have 15 reps yet.